# Rails 3 + Devise with different model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm sharing one database for two web applications. The User model is already being used for one of these apps, so, in order to sign in to the other one, I had to create another model to avoid mixing users info.

I could make Devise work for this new model, called SystemUser. The problem is now I'll have to use every variable with another name. For example: `current_system_user`, `system_user_signed_in?`, etc. I'm using these variables, with their original name, across the whole application, and I would like to know if there's a way to avoid overwriting it. For example: by creating a method called `current_user` that returns `current_system_user`, and that way with the other variables mentioned before.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible terrible idea, and will return to bite you.

Comment: Either: 1) Share user accounts across applications, or, 2) Don't share a database - expose an API instead.

Comment: I thought about using a different database. But the problem isn't the DB, it's the model's name. I mean, its when the model is called other than "User".

Comment: Sharing databases between Rails applications is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: Let's say I use a separate database for this app. The problem will be still there, because I already have a User model in my app, making reference to another database.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you have two databases for your application. I'm suggesting that your application have one database, and that no other application touches that database. If you need to share data between your applications you should consider an API.

Comment: I know. The thing is that I cannot change the way the app has been built, so I just have to use Devise with SystemUser model instead of User. That's it. If I could make the following line to work, I'll be more than happy:

Comment: devise_for :users, :class_name => "SystemUser", :controllers => {:sessions => "user_sessions"}, :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :registration => 'register'}

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: 'SystemUser'
```

Comment: This is the line for Devise in routes.rb:    devise_for :users, :class_name => "SystemUser", :controllers => {:sessions => "user_sessions"},
             :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :registration => 'register'}

Comment: Output for `rake routes`? What is in your `UserSessionsController` ?

Comment: That controller is empty. What should I write there?

Comment: Why is it empty if you have `{:sessions => "user_sessions"}` in your `routes.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using CanCan for roles?

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: It's not a roles issue. I must use a different model's name for logging in, and it's not the one that Devise uses as default.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally solve the issue by generating the Devise views again. I don't know why, but the devise/sessions folder was missing, and it was doing it with another view, and when I started using it, it worked.

Thanks anyway.